# How to pass an integer as a command line argument in c?

Tags: c

I have the following code below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int n = argv[1];
  function1(n);

}
```

Naturally, my code gives an error because argv[] is a pointer to a char. I want to run the program with an integer that gets passed and used by a function called "function1."
For example:

```
./program 5
```

How do I do this with any input, so that the n is equal to that input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get argv\[\] as int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748393/how-can-i-get-argv-as-int)

Comment: argv is not a pointer to a char, but am array of char*, which are strings. So you need a function that converts char* to int, google is your friend from here

Comment: You can use atoi() to convert argv[1] to int